# Having problems installing Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have windows 10 64 bit installed as legacy. I tried to boot Ubuntu from a USB drive but it directly live booted without asking whether to live boot or install it. Anyway I tried to install it by the desktop software. But at a point it gave me a warning that Ubuntu is UEFI and I was trying to install it in legacy. Even though I continued but it didn't give me an option to multi-boot with windows.
I created the live USB from Linux Live USB creator and Universal USB Installer but the result was same.
I am new to Ubuntu so if I am doing it incorrectly please provide some suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Can you press a specific key which will open the boot manager during the start-up of your pc? I had a HP 250 G3 notebook, and when in legacy mode it still booted Ubuntu as UEFI, so I had to open the boot manager and choose to boot the USB with Ubuntu which had (legacy) written at the end.

Comment: Yes, I pressed F12 to open boot menu. All other drives were under Legacy menu whereas the USB drive was under UEFI menu.

Comment: It was my own mistake. There was USB mass storage listed among legacy menu

Comment: Now it should work in theory.